# what kind of html element is the mui autocomplete?

Tags: typescript, material-ui

I am trying to call a function that handles onchange on autocomplete mui element, the event for the I tried e: React.ChangeEvent
but I cannot find the element for the autocomplete component it gives the following error

Type '(e: React.ChangeEvent) => void' is not assignable to type '(event: ChangeEvent<{}>, value: string | null, reason: AutocompleteChangeReason, details?: AutocompleteChangeDetails | undefined) => void'.

any idea how to handle this element ?

```js
// Function 
const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>): void => {
  //some logic 
 };
 const handleTextField = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    setText(e.target.value);
  };
 
 // Element 
   <Autocomplete
          id='combo-box-demo'
          key={bool}
          options={options}
          getOptionLabel={(option) => option}
          onChange={handleChange}
          className={classes.root}
          renderInput={(params) => (
            <TextField
              onChange={handleTextField}
              {...params}
              InputLabelProps={{ shrink: false }}
              label={!text.length && !e ? props.e + ' e' : ' '}
            />
          )}
        />
```

[image]

Comment: What MUI version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the value from the `onChange` event, you should use the second parameter as shown [here](https://mui.com/components/autocomplete/#ControllableStates.tsx)

Also, the event type must be `React.ChangeEvent`.

[Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-gygzac?file=demo.tsx) is a demo I created for you

Your `onChange` function should be like this:

```
const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent, value: string | null): void => {
    console.log({ e, value });
};
```

Update:
As you said in the comments, you are trying to use the same `onChange` handler for the native `select` and `autocomplete` components.
You should separate that two logic.

```
  const handleNativeSelectChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>) => {
    setSelected({ ...selected, [`${e.target.name}`]: e.target.value });
  }
  const handleMuiChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent, value: string | null) => {
    setSelected({ ...selected, item: value });
  }
  const handleChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent, value: string | null): void => {
    if (!!e.target.closest("button")) {
      setSelected({ ...selected, item: "" });
      setText("");
      return;
    }

    if (e.target.id.startsWith("combo")) {
      handleMuiChange(e, value)
    } else {
      handleNativeSelectChange(e as React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement>)
    }
  };
```

Comment: could using any is justified here ?

Comment: Since the types are already specified, I don't recommend using `any`. But If you want, of course, you can. Is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: I am using the same function on 2 elements but for some reason in my local code unless i put any it refuse to compile, https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-vsz89?file=/demo.tsx

Comment: so i need a specific html element for the autocomplete other than any.

Comment: the current version I am mui 4

Comment: use `React.ChangeEvent` instead of `React.ChangeEvent<HTMLSelectElement | any>` and add this line to use as target element variable. `const target = e.target as HTMLElement;` After this line, you should access target element by `target` variable. Don't use `e.target`.
Also, to get the value please use the second parameter as I show in my answer

Comment: Casting as HTMLElement showing Property 'name' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'

Comment: Oh I see, didn't realize you are using native select too. It should be better if you separate that two logic. I will try a solution and let you know

Comment: there is still a missing HTML element for some reason. adding pic to question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/238742/discussion-between-fatihsolhan-and-richardson).